# ElasticSearch/Painless: How do I skip an item when iterating?

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, elasticsearch-painless

I have a for loop that iterates a list. If the list contains a certain value, say "5", I want the loop to *skip* that value. But Painless seems determined to not permit that by not letting me have an empty if block or use a continue statement. **How can I accomplish this?**

```
"script_fields": {
"HResultCount": {
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "int instance = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc['numbers'].length; ++i) { if (doc['numbers'] == '5') { /* bail out */ } else { return 1.0; } }" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have to return a value in all cases, so the question is what do you want to return when the value is 5?

Comment: Is there a mechanism to remove 5's from the list before I iterate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a script has to return a value in all cases, you can remove the value 5 from the list before iterating as you suggested.

You can achieve this like that by calling `removeIf` on a copy of your list with a Java 8 lambda:

```
"script_fields": {
"HResultCount": {
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "int instance = 0; List copy = new ArrayList(doc['numbers']); copy.removeIf(i -> i == 5); for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; ++i) { instance += copy[i]; } return instance;" 
  }
}
```